# Fatal server error: no screens found

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I am trying to install a new graphics card (Nvidia GeForce 6800 GT) but am having problems.

Whenever I boot I get to tty-1, and startx gives me a "Fatal server error: no screens found". I apparently have nvidia-current and have tried removing and then re-installing but this has not affected the error.

Below is the output of xorg.0.log

```
[    32.755] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[    32.755] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    32.755] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-37-generic i686 Ubuntu
[    32.755] Current Operating System: Linux pcuser-System 3.2.0-57-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 21:38:12 UTC 2013 i686
[    32.755] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-57-generic root=UUID=36d22074-628d-4ee6-96db-8db605d1f147 ro quiet splash
[    32.755] Build Date: 16 October 2013  04:45:22PM
[    32.755] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.14 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    32.755] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[    32.755]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    32.755] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    32.755] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Dec 10 20:17:05 2013
[    32.755] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    32.755] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    32.755] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    32.755] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen" (0)
[    32.755] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    32.756] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen".
    Using the first device section listed.
[    32.756] (**) |   |-->Device "Default Device"
[    32.756] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    32.756] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    32.756] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[missing fonts
[    32.756]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    32.756] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[    32.756] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    32.756] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    32.756] (II) Loader magic: 0xf6e5a0
[    32.756] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    32.756]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    32.756]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[    32.756]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[    32.756]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[    32.757] (--) PCI:*(0:2:0:0) 10de:06e4:196e:05cc rev 161, Mem @ 0xfb000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xf8000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000ec00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    32.757] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    32.757] (II) "extmod" will be loaded by default.
[    32.757] (II) "dbe" will be loaded by default.
[    32.757] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[    32.757] (II) "record" will be loaded by default.
[    32.757] (II) "dri" will be loaded by default.
[    32.757] (II) "dri2" will be loaded by default.
[    32.757] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    32.757] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/libglx.so
[    32.781] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    32.781]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    32.781]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    32.781] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:51:59 PDT 2013
[    32.781] (II) Loading extension GLX
[    32.781] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    32.802] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[    32.802] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.802]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    32.802]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    32.803]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[    32.803] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    32.803] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[    32.803] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.803]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    32.803]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    32.803]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    32.803] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[    32.803] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[    32.803] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.803]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[    32.803]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    32.803]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[    32.803] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[    32.803] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[    32.803] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.803]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    32.803]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    32.803] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[    32.803] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    32.804] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    32.804] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.804]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    32.804]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    32.804] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    32.804] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    32.804] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    32.804] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[    32.804] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    32.804] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    32.804] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    32.804] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    32.804] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/nvidia_drv.so
[    32.804] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    32.804]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    32.804]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    32.804] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    32.804] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    32.804] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.804]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.16
[    32.804]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    32.804]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    32.804] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    32.805] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    32.805] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    32.805] (II) Unloading nv
[    32.805] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    32.805] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    32.805] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    32.805] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.805]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.3.0
[    32.805]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    32.805]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    32.805] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    32.805] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    32.805] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.805]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[    32.805]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    32.805] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[    32.805] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 1
[    32.805] (==) Matched nv as autoconfigured driver 2
[    32.805] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[    32.805] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 4
[    32.805] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    32.805] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    32.805] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/nvidia_drv.so
[    32.805] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    32.805]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    32.805]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    32.805] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[    32.805] (II) Unloading nvidia
[    32.805] (II) Failed to load module "nvidia" (already loaded, 15944731)
[    32.805] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[    32.806] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[    32.806] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.806]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.16
[    32.806]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    32.806]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    32.806] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    32.806] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    32.806] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 15944731)
[    32.806] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
[    32.806] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nv
[    32.806] (II) UnloadModule: "nv"
[    32.806] (II) Unloading nv
[    32.806] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[    32.806] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    32.806] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    32.806] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.806]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.3.0
[    32.806]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    32.806]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    32.806] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    32.806] (II) Unloading vesa
[    32.806] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[    32.806] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    32.806] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    32.806] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.806]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.4.2
[    32.806]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    32.806] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    32.806] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    32.806] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[    32.806] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:32:42 PDT 2013
[    32.806] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    32.806] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Wed Nov 30 18:56:54 2011 +0100
[    32.806] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[    32.806]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[    32.806]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[    32.806]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[    32.806]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[    32.806]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[    32.806]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[    32.806]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[    32.806]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[    32.806]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[    32.806]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[    32.806]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[    32.807]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[    32.807]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[    32.807] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    32.807] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    32.807] (++) using VT number 7

[    32.808] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    32.808] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    32.808] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    32.808] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.808]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    32.808]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    32.808] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    32.808] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    32.808] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    32.808] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.808]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    32.808]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    32.808] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    32.808] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    32.808] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    32.808] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/nvidia_drv.so
[    32.808] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    32.808] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    32.808] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    32.808] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    32.808] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    32.808] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    32.808] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    32.808] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    32.809]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    32.809]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 11.0
[    32.809] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[    32.809] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    32.809] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    32.809] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    32.809] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    32.809] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    32.809] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" "True"
[    32.809] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    33.578] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[    33.578] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[    33.579] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 8400 GS (G98) at PCI:2:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    33.579] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 524288 kBytes
[    33.579] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 62.98.71.00.52
[    33.579] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    33.579] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    33.582] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GeForce 8400 GS at PCI:2:0:0
[    33.582] (--) NVIDIA(0):     LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0) (connected)
[    33.582] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-1
[    33.583] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[    33.583] (--) NVIDIA(0): LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    33.583] (--) NVIDIA(0): CRT-1: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    33.583] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    33.583] (--) NVIDIA(0): DFP-0: Internal Single Link TMDS
[    33.583] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    33.583] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[    33.583] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[    33.585] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    33.585] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    33.585] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    33.585] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    33.585] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    33.585] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    33.585] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1680 x 1050
[    33.621] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (87, 83); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    33.621] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    33.621] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[    33.621] (II) Unloading nouveau
[    33.621] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    33.621] (II) Unloading vesa
[    33.621] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    33.621] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    33.621] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    33.621] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    33.621] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    33.622] (II) NVIDIA: Using 768.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory access.
[    33.628] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "CRT-0:nvidia-auto-select"
[    33.654] (II) Loading extension NV-GLX
[    33.680] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    33.680] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[    33.680] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    33.680] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    33.680] (II) Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    33.681] (II) Loading extension XINERAMA
[    33.681] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    33.681] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    33.681] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    33.681] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.681]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    33.681]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    33.681] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    33.681] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    33.681] (--) RandR disabled
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    33.681] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    33.681] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    33.706] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    33.708] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    33.708] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    33.708] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    33.708] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    33.708] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    33.708]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.7.0
[    33.708]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    33.708]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
[    33.708] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    33.708] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    33.708] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    33.708] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    33.708] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    33.708] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    33.708] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    33.708] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    33.708] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    33.708] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    33.708] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    33.708] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    33.710] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2B4266AA55228AE7D9557A18F1965DBA19850816.xkm
[    33.711] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    33.711] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    33.711] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    33.711] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    33.711] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    33.711] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    33.711] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    33.711] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    33.711] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    33.711] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    33.711] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    33.711] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    33.711] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    33.711] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    33.711] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 (/dev/input/event2)
[    33.711] (**) Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    33.711] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000'
[    33.711] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[...keyboard info...
[    33.711] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/input/input2/event2"
[    33.711] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    33.711] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    33.711] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    33.711] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    33.712] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Microsoft Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 (/dev/input/event3)
[ ...keyboard info... threshold: 4
[    33.713] (II) config/udev: Adding input device www.tigerfly.net www.tigerfly.net (/dev/input/event4)
[    33.713] (**) www.tigerfly.net www.tigerfly.net: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    33.713] (**) www.tigerfly.net www.tigerfly.net: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    33.713] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'www.tigerfly.net www.tigerfly.net'
[    33.713] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    33.713] (**) www.tigerfly.net www.tigerfly.net: always reports core events
[    33.713] (**) evdev: www.tigerfly.net www.tigerfly.net: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[...mouse info... (/dev/input/js0)
[    33.714] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.714] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    33.714] (II) config/udev: Adding input device www.tigerfly.net www.tigerfly.net (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    33.714] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.714] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    33.714] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Line-Out CLFE (/dev/input/event10)
[    33.714] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.714] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    33.714] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Line-Out Surround (/dev/input/event11)
[    33.714] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.714] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    33.714] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Line-Out Front (/dev/input/event12)
[    33.714] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.714] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    33.714] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Line (/dev/input/event5)
[    33.714] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.714] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    33.715] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Front Mic (/dev/input/event6)
[    33.715] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.715] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    33.715] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Rear Mic (/dev/input/event7)
[    33.715] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.715] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    33.715] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Front Headphone (/dev/input/event8)
[    33.715] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.715] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    33.715] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia Line-Out Side (/dev/input/event9)
[    33.715] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    33.715] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.562] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[    35.562] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[    35.562] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    35.562] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[    35.563] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[    37.048] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[    37.048] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[    37.048] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    37.048] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[    37.048] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[    39.360] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[    39.360] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[    39.360] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    39.360] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[    39.360] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
[    41.680] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-03AF3717FF3AB439A4BAABA686CCB40771CDF520.xkm
[    47.673] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101b (/dev/input/event13)
[    47.673] (**) Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101b: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    47.673] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101b'
[    47.673] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
    [    47.673] (**) Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101b: always reports core events
...truncated...
EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    47.673] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/usb4/4-5/4-5:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0006/input/input13/event13"
[    47.673] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101b" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[    47.673] (II) evdev: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101b: initialized for relative axes.
[truncated
[    47.674] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101b (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    47.674] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    47.674] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    56.904] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[    56.904] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[    56.904] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    56.904] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device LG Electronics W2252 (CRT-0) (Using EDID
[    56.904] (**) NVIDIA(0):     frequencies has been enabled on all display devices.)
```

I had to truncate some bits as it's 35000 chars! They are denoted [...(info type)...

Comment: I think log files of such size are much better of on a [pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) site.

Comment: I think that if instead you use `sudo service lightdm start` instead of `startx` is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this graphics card requires a separate power supply and I didn't realise. (It was a gift and came with no packaging, I'd not used an independently powered gfx card before.) D'OH!